# Compare link on detail page

Tags: magento-1.7, url, compare

I need to implement Compare button as a link on product detail page.

What I trying to do:

```
<span><a class="btn-compare" onclick="popWin('<?php echo $_helper->getListUrl() ?>','compare','top:0,left:0,width=820,height=600,resizable=yes,scrollbars=yes')"><?php echo $this->__('Compare') ?></a><span>
```

Problem is $_helper->getListUrl()  return strange link:

```
string 'my.dev/catalog/product_compare/index/uenc/aHR0cDovL2F0ZXguZGV2L2xpY2h0LWlua29vcC9iaW5uZW52ZXJsaWNodGluZy9wbGFmb25kLWluYm91dy90ZWtuaWx1eC03MzQ4NS5odG1s/' (length=160)
```

it's opening and closing in a second, there no products also.

Link must be `my.dev/catalog/product_compate/index/`.

Thanks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try replacing `$_helper->getListUrl()` with

```
$this->getUrl('catalog/product_compare/index')
```

**[EDIT]**

And make sure you have products in the comparison list.

Comment: thanks for reply, it's showing and closing after second...

Comment: Do you have any products added to the comparison list?

Comment: Yes, there set  if($_helper->getItemCount() > 0): and I just add product on detail page and press link.

Comment: I'm just update database, and it's working, probably was something with DB settings.